# OIM Entitlement created without a request no#

Tags: task, provisioning, entitlements

I have some Manual Fulfillment Task (MFT) to grant entitlements that does not include a request#. How to troubleshoot this issue? How to troubleshoot entitlement issues?

I am new to this process. I have searched the entitlement tables.
I need to know how to find the record Manual Fulfillment Task (MFT) with the missing request no# and how to fix the issue to ensure that all requests generate a request no#.